# Can not cast LocalSessionfactory to SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate **5.4.0.Final** and Spring **4.3.13.RELEASE** I have written following code

```
@Bean
    public SessionFactory sharedDataSessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(sharedDataSource());
        builder.scanPackages("com.some.package", "scom.some.package1");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", MySQL5InnoDBDialect.class);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", false);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", false);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", false);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 25);
        builder.addProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerSharedData() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sharedDataSessionFactory());
  }
```

But when I run test code it gives exception like this

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManagerSharedData' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6b39340 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6b39340 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory
    at se.ss.some.backend.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2342b23c.sharedDataSessionFactory(<generated>)
    at se.ss.some.backend.config.HibernateConfig.transactionManagerSharedData(HibernateConfig.java:106)
    at se.ss.some.backend.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2342b23c.CGLIB$transactionManagerSharedData$5(<generated>)
    at se.ss.some.backend.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2342b23c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c29b43a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at se.mindspot.tender.backend.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2342b23c.transactionManagerSharedData(<generated>

)
```

But my application run fine with this code. What is the cause to cast this class???

Comment: please can you share project in github ? and add me shaaban.altanany@gmail.com as a contributor

Comment: sorry its not possible to share full codebase

Comment: you can make small project to simulate it to help you that is  all

Comment: I resolved it. some spring configuration was missing. Thanks anyway for help.